# See last comment or stream tag for each friend

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

So right now this looks like:

```
$mq = array(
    "usr"=>"SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() LIMIT 70",
    "basics"=>"SELECT name, uid FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM #usr)",
    "q1" =>"SELECT actor_id FROM stream_tag WHERE target_id = me() AND actor_id IN (SELECT uid2 FROM #usr)",
    "q2" =>"SELECT target_id FROM stream_tag WHERE target_id IN (SELECT uid2 FROM #usr) AND actor_id = me()"
);
```

I'm trying to get interactions between each active users friends. Any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve the same result with something more simple like:

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id
FROM stream_tag 
WHERE target_id=me() OR actor_id=me()
```

hope this helps

Comment: Well the reason I require the AND is so it only pulls tags where equal on both ends (friend to user / user to friend), based on each user friend id (all squished into a single multi-query)

Comment: >>where equal on both ends<< what exactly is equal here? I'm afraid don't get you...

Comment: Basically the multiquery i've set up (above) pulls all your friend's ids.  So q1 and q2 (of the MFQL array) return a response on each iterated person; so if set to "OR" will then return XX+ instead of X{1} per user.  Appreciate the help though.